# I want to remove bulk related products and then needs to update fresh skus

Tags: magento

I have tried using php script to remove the related products. But not the way I wanted things.

Is there a way I can remove the related products links and then update the fresh ones.

Comment: please update your question. it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Which examples you tried? Could you give us some code you need to fix? Take a tour in the help center to ask better questions and therefore receive more useful answers! You can start here: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

to remove all product link relations you could do

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE link_type_id = 1
```